# CSV file is downloaded instead of opened in browser

Tags: java, angular, typescript, csv, jhipster

I'm using Jhipster and Jhipster generate a function to open file in browser. The problem is: I don't understand so much the function, and I don't know why, when the file is a CSV file, the file is not opened in the browser but downloaded. It works for other file, like XML, but not for CSV.

Here the code :

```
  openFile(data: string, contentType: string | null | undefined): void {
    contentType = contentType ?? '';

    const byteCharacters = atob(data);
    const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    const blob = new Blob([byteArray], {
      type: contentType,
    });
    const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const win = window.open(fileURL);
    win!.onload = function () {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
    };
  }
```

If anyone has an idea, It will be really helpful. Thanks !

Comment: What if you do `contentType = 'text/plain';`? Check what the content type is now.

Comment: The content type was text/csv. I tried to change contentType by 'text/plain', It works ! There is absolutely no layout but it works, thanks!

Comment: The only way for a sheet like layout is if the browser would open Excel or LibreOffice, there are content types for that too. But there is no guarantee. One thing more: the charset must be correct for special characters like comma-like quotes, bullet, € sign or é and such. **Answer your own question, if you do not want to continue asking.**

Comment: Is it possible to open LibreOffice with browser ? I'm not sure about that for security reasons.

Comment: For CSV there should be no problem (no macros). However browser integration, browser plugins to map text/csv to Libra Office is a user side configuration. Only feasible for a company net. You could try the mime type for Excel. It even might work. But yes, users might consider it an unsafe, tainted way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create a new route /csv-view (the button redirect on this route) and transform the content in a array of strings and then a html table.